# How to get index of clicked point in scatter plot

Tags: highcharts

How to get index of an clicked point in scatter plot

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (event) {
                        alert('X: ' + this.x); 
                         alert('Index : ' + this.value); 
                    }
                }
            },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
                [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
                [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
                [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
                [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
                [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
                [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
                [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3],
                [167.6, 58.3], [165.1, 56.2], [160.0, 50.2], [170.0, 72.9], [157.5, 59.8],
                [167.6, 61.0], [160.7, 69.1], [163.2, 55.9], [152.4, 46.5], [157.5, 54.3],
                [168.3, 54.8], [180.3, 60.7], [165.5, 60.0], [165.0, 62.0], [164.5, 60.3],
                [156.0, 52.7], [160.0, 74.3], [163.0, 62.0], [165.7, 73.1], [161.0, 80.0],
                [162.0, 54.7], [166.0, 53.2], [174.0, 75.7], [172.7, 61.1], [167.6, 55.7],
                [151.1, 48.7], [164.5, 52.3], [163.5, 50.0], [152.0, 59.3], [169.0, 62.5],
                [164.0, 55.7], [161.2, 54.8], [155.0, 45.9], [170.0, 70.6], [176.2, 67.2],
                [170.0, 69.4], [162.5, 58.2], [170.3, 64.8], [164.1, 71.6], [169.5, 52.8],
                [163.2, 59.8], [154.5, 49.0], [159.8, 50.0], [173.2, 69.2], [170.0, 55.9],
                [161.4, 63.4], [169.0, 58.2], [166.2, 58.6], [159.4, 45.7], [162.5, 52.2],
                [159.0, 48.6], [162.8, 57.8], [159.0, 55.6], [179.8, 66.8], [162.9, 59.4],
                [161.0, 53.6], [151.1, 73.2], [168.2, 53.4], [168.9, 69.0], [173.2, 58.4],
                [171.8, 56.2], [178.0, 70.6], [164.3, 59.8], [163.0, 72.0], [168.5, 65.2],
                [166.8, 56.6], [172.7, 105.2], [163.5, 51.8], [169.4, 63.4], [167.8, 59.0],
                [159.5, 47.6], [167.6, 63.0], [161.2, 55.2], [160.0, 45.0], [163.2, 54.0],
                [162.2, 50.2], [161.3, 60.2], [149.5, 44.8], [157.5, 58.8], [163.2, 56.4],
                [172.7, 62.0], [155.0, 49.2], [156.5, 67.2], [164.0, 53.8], [160.9, 54.4],
                [162.8, 58.0], [167.0, 59.8], [160.0, 54.8], [160.0, 43.2], [168.9, 60.5],
                [158.2, 46.4], [156.0, 64.4], [160.0, 48.8], [167.1, 62.2], [158.0, 55.5],
                [167.6, 57.8], [156.0, 54.6], [162.1, 59.2], [173.4, 52.7], [159.8, 53.2],
                [170.5, 64.5], [159.2, 51.8], [157.5, 56.0], [161.3, 63.6], [162.6, 63.2],
                [160.0, 59.5], [168.9, 56.8], [165.1, 64.1], [162.6, 50.0], [165.1, 72.3],
                [166.4, 55.0], [160.0, 55.9], [152.4, 60.4], [170.2, 69.1], [162.6, 84.5],
                [170.2, 55.9], [158.8, 55.5], [172.7, 69.5], [167.6, 76.4], [162.6, 61.4],
                [167.6, 65.9], [156.2, 58.6], [175.2, 66.8], [172.1, 56.6], [162.6, 58.6],
                [160.0, 55.9], [165.1, 59.1], [182.9, 81.8], [166.4, 70.7], [165.1, 56.8],
                [177.8, 60.0], [165.1, 58.2], [175.3, 72.7], [154.9, 54.1], [158.8, 49.1],
                [172.7, 75.9], [168.9, 55.0], [161.3, 57.3], [167.6, 55.0], [165.1, 65.5],
                [175.3, 65.5], [157.5, 48.6], [163.8, 58.6], [167.6, 63.6], [165.1, 55.2],
                [165.1, 62.7], [168.9, 56.6], [162.6, 53.9], [164.5, 63.2], [176.5, 73.6],
                [168.9, 62.0], [175.3, 63.6], [159.4, 53.2], [160.0, 53.4], [170.2, 55.0],
                [162.6, 70.5], [167.6, 54.5], [162.6, 54.5], [160.7, 55.9], [160.0, 59.0],
                [157.5, 63.6], [162.6, 54.5], [152.4, 47.3], [170.2, 67.7], [165.1, 80.9],
                [172.7, 70.5], [165.1, 60.9], [170.2, 63.6], [170.2, 54.5], [170.2, 59.1],
                [161.3, 70.5], [167.6, 52.7], [167.6, 62.7], [165.1, 86.3], [162.6, 66.4],
                [152.4, 67.3], [168.9, 63.0], [170.2, 73.6], [175.2, 62.3], [175.2, 57.7],
                [160.0, 55.4], [165.1, 104.1], [174.0, 55.5], [170.2, 77.3], [160.0, 80.5],
                [167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4], [154.9, 58.2], [162.6, 81.8],
                [175.3, 63.6], [171.4, 53.4], [157.5, 54.5], [165.1, 53.6], [160.0, 60.0],
                [174.0, 73.6], [162.6, 61.4], [174.0, 55.5], [162.6, 63.6], [161.3, 60.9],
                [156.2, 60.0], [149.9, 46.8], [169.5, 57.3], [160.0, 64.1], [175.3, 63.6],
                [169.5, 67.3], [160.0, 75.5], [172.7, 68.2], [162.6, 61.4], [157.5, 76.8],
                [176.5, 71.8], [164.4, 55.5], [160.7, 48.6], [174.0, 66.4], [163.8, 67.3]]

        }, {
            name: 'Male',
            color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
            data: [[174.0, 65.6], [175.3, 71.8], [193.5, 80.7], [186.5, 72.6], [187.2, 78.8],
                [181.5, 74.8], [184.0, 86.4], [184.5, 78.4], [175.0, 62.0], [184.0, 81.6],
                [180.0, 76.6], [177.8, 83.6], [192.0, 90.0], [176.0, 74.6], [174.0, 71.0],
                [184.0, 79.6], [192.7, 93.8], [171.5, 70.0], [173.0, 72.4], [176.0, 85.9],
                [176.0, 78.8], [180.5, 77.8], [172.7, 66.2], [176.0, 86.4], [173.5, 81.8],
                [178.0, 89.6], [180.3, 82.8], [180.3, 76.4], [164.5, 63.2], [173.0, 60.9],
                [183.5, 74.8], [175.5, 70.0], [188.0, 72.4], [189.2, 84.1], [172.8, 69.1],
                [170.0, 59.5], [182.0, 67.2], [170.0, 61.3], [177.8, 68.6], [184.2, 80.1],
                [186.7, 87.8], [171.4, 84.7], [172.7, 73.4], [175.3, 72.1], [180.3, 82.6],
                [182.9, 88.7], [188.0, 84.1], [177.2, 94.1], [172.1, 74.9], [167.0, 59.1],
                [169.5, 75.6], [174.0, 86.2], [172.7, 75.3], [182.2, 87.1], [164.1, 55.2],
                [163.0, 57.0], [171.5, 61.4], [184.2, 76.8], [174.0, 86.8], [174.0, 72.2],
                [177.0, 71.6], [186.0, 84.8], [167.0, 68.2], [171.8, 66.1], [182.0, 72.0],
                [167.0, 64.6], [177.8, 74.8], [164.5, 70.0], [192.0, 101.6], [175.5, 63.2],
                [171.2, 79.1], [181.6, 78.9], [167.4, 67.7], [181.1, 66.0], [177.0, 68.2],
                [174.5, 63.9], [177.5, 72.0], [170.5, 56.8], [182.4, 74.5], [197.1, 90.9],
                [180.1, 93.0], [175.5, 80.9], [180.6, 72.7], [184.4, 68.0], [175.5, 70.9],
                [180.6, 72.5], [177.0, 72.5], [177.1, 83.4], [181.6, 75.5], [176.5, 73.0],
                [175.0, 70.2], [174.0, 73.4], [165.1, 70.5], [177.0, 68.9], [192.0, 102.3],
                [176.5, 68.4], [169.4, 65.9], [182.1, 75.7], [179.8, 84.5], [175.3, 87.7],
                [184.9, 86.4], [177.3, 73.2], [167.4, 53.9], [178.1, 72.0], [168.9, 55.5],
                [157.2, 58.4], [180.3, 83.2], [170.2, 72.7], [177.8, 64.1], [172.7, 72.3],
                [165.1, 65.0], [186.7, 86.4], [165.1, 65.0], [174.0, 88.6], [175.3, 84.1],
                [185.4, 66.8], [177.8, 75.5], [180.3, 93.2], [180.3, 82.7], [177.8, 58.0],
                [177.8, 79.5], [177.8, 78.6], [177.8, 71.8], [177.8, 116.4], [163.8, 72.2],
                [188.0, 83.6], [198.1, 85.5], [175.3, 90.9], [166.4, 85.9], [190.5, 89.1],
                [166.4, 75.0], [177.8, 77.7], [179.7, 86.4], [172.7, 90.9], [190.5, 73.6],
                [185.4, 76.4], [168.9, 69.1], [167.6, 84.5], [175.3, 64.5], [170.2, 69.1],
                [190.5, 108.6], [177.8, 86.4], [190.5, 80.9], [177.8, 87.7], [184.2, 94.5],
                [176.5, 80.2], [177.8, 72.0], [180.3, 71.4], [171.4, 72.7], [172.7, 84.1],
                [172.7, 76.8], [177.8, 63.6], [177.8, 80.9], [182.9, 80.9], [170.2, 85.5],
                [167.6, 68.6], [175.3, 67.7], [165.1, 66.4], [185.4, 102.3], [181.6, 70.5],
                [172.7, 95.9], [190.5, 84.1], [179.1, 87.3], [175.3, 71.8], [170.2, 65.9],
                [193.0, 95.9], [171.4, 91.4], [177.8, 81.8], [177.8, 96.8], [167.6, 69.1],
                [167.6, 82.7], [180.3, 75.5], [182.9, 79.5], [176.5, 73.6], [186.7, 91.8],
                [188.0, 84.1], [188.0, 85.9], [177.8, 81.8], [174.0, 82.5], [177.8, 80.5],
                [171.4, 70.0], [185.4, 81.8], [185.4, 84.1], [188.0, 90.5], [188.0, 91.4],
                [182.9, 89.1], [176.5, 85.0], [175.3, 69.1], [175.3, 73.6], [188.0, 80.5],
                [188.0, 82.7], [175.3, 86.4], [170.5, 67.7], [179.1, 92.7], [177.8, 93.6],
                [175.3, 70.9], [182.9, 75.0], [170.8, 93.2], [188.0, 93.2], [180.3, 77.7],
                [177.8, 61.4], [185.4, 94.1], [168.9, 75.0], [185.4, 83.6], [180.3, 85.5],
                [174.0, 73.9], [167.6, 66.8], [182.9, 87.3], [160.0, 72.3], [180.3, 88.6],
                [167.6, 75.5], [186.7, 101.4], [175.3, 91.1], [175.3, 67.3], [175.9, 77.7],
                [175.3, 81.8], [179.1, 75.5], [181.6, 84.5], [177.8, 76.6], [182.9, 85.0],
                [177.8, 102.5], [184.2, 77.3], [179.1, 71.8], [176.5, 87.9], [188.0, 94.3],
                [174.0, 70.9], [167.6, 64.5], [170.2, 77.3], [167.6, 72.3], [188.0, 87.3],
                [174.0, 80.0], [176.5, 82.3], [180.3, 73.6], [167.6, 74.1], [188.0, 85.9],
                [180.3, 73.2], [167.6, 76.3], [183.0, 65.9], [183.0, 90.9], [179.1, 89.1],
                [170.2, 62.3], [177.8, 82.7], [179.1, 79.1], [190.5, 98.2], [177.8, 84.1],
                [180.3, 83.2], [180.3, 83.2]]
        }]
    });
});
```

For Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KQ6Uk/6/

Answer (score 1):

Points are not indexed in Highcharts. You can change format from array: `[x, y]` to object: `{x: x, y:y, index}`. Then in callback you can access that property: `this.options.myIndex`.